# Crushftp with Spring batch

Tags: spring, spring-batch, sftp

Have anyone tried using spring batch with crush ftp to upload/download files? Is the DefaultSftpSessionFactory provided by the spring framework is enough to integrate crushftp or i need a custom class to handle the file upload/download and login?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: That's outside the scope of Spring Batch, but any code that uploads/downloads files from an ftp server can be put in a custom tasklet step as part of a batch job.